# Which order for vector of vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I am using a structure `std::vector< std::vector<double> >` to store 2D data in a C++ code of size NxM. Is there any performance issue related to the order in which I store my data if N is very different than M?

For instance, let's say N = 3 and M = 100000, I suppose it is faster to build 3 vectors of size 100000 than 100000 vectors of size 3. But for instance, if I am using a lot of `push_back` to fill them (assuming I don't know the initial size), isn't the other method faster ?

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, a better decision might be to use just one `std::vector` with some index arithmetic.

Comment: I guess this is is a matrix, or at least equivalent. For that, just do a bit of research looking for efficient implementations and/or discussions here concerning that topic.

Comment: @Evg that's definitely a better idea but it only works if at least N _or_ M is known. I assume OP wants to store e.g. coordinates for which N = 3 but M is unknown, in which case your suggestion would work (and you'd have caching etc working for you, as long as you're not iterating over x coordinates only).

Comment: I actually know about one coordinate only, (at runtime). I could indeed use a single vector, but I use methods over both dimensions once my vectors are built, which is why I came up with vector of vectors, to avoid arithmetics afterwards. I am not sure it is so problematic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I suppose it is faster to build 3 vectors of size 100000 than 100000
>   vectors of size 3.*

Almost certainly, yes (and *considerably* so)!

> *... if I am using a lot of push_back to fill them (assuming I don't
>   know the initial size).*

If you at least know (or suspect) what the *maximum size* is likely to be, you could use the [`reserve(nMax)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) function before your loop with the `push_back` calls, then call [`shrink_to_fit(nAct)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) afterwards, to free unneeded memory. Such an approach would reduce the overheads caused by (potentially many) re-allocation calls.